# how to call javascript function with $.post and get html data with css of the initial page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i have a drop down list when i choose element i call a javascript function, this function load contents from another php file like below:

```
function load_new_content(){
 var selected_option_value=$("#select1 option:selected").val(); 
 $.post("patient-maximumunit.php", {option_value: selected_option_value},
     function(data){ 
          $("#patientselected").html(data);
         
     }
 );
 }
```

this function display a html table from the file `patient-maximumunit.php`
the problem is the table displayed in this page is not loading using the css of the initial page, the css file of the first page is not loaded in the `patient-maximumunit.php`

Comment: What's the problem with including that CSS in this page?

Comment: if i include the css file the page is not loaded any more

Comment: of the style is not diplaying as i want

Comment: Sounds like your issue arises from CSS and has nothing to do with PHP or JS.

Comment: Think of it this way: ajax is used to load *data*, not to parse an html page. So if you want your *data* to be styled with css, the css needs to be on the page loading the data. You can also use jquery to assign or remove classes after the fact. BTW, you should be loading an html fragment, not a fully formed html page.